# Javascript | Can´t show session variable with alert

Tags: javascript

I am new in Javascript world, for any reason, alert can´t show 7. It is a simple example of saving in session variable and retrieving it. Why?

Thanks!

**Javascript:**

```js
var corrects = 7;
sessionStorage.setItem('corrects', corrects);
corrects = sessionStorage.setItem('corrects');
alert("corrects:" + corrects);
```

Comment: Open the developer tools in your browser. Look at the console. **Read the error message**. Fix the *typo*.

Comment: you misspelled window

Comment: first set then get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Guess what you want to do and write the answer

```
var corrects = 7;
sessionStorage.setItem('corrects', corrects);
corrects = sessionStorage.getItem('corrects');
alert("corrects:" + corrects);
```

## Explanation

```
window.sessionStorage.getItem('corrects', corrects);
```

the `getItem` method cannot take two arguments, and the `getItem` method is used for **Get**, not for save.
You save data with `setItem` method.

Comment: Thank's shingo.nakanishi. Sorry for the basic mistakes. I understand the negative vote. Thank´s for all. ; )

Answer (score 0):

The error was very basic. The use of the setItem and getItem was incorrect. We use setItem for save and getItem for get.

Example:

```
<script>
var corrects = 7;
sessionStorage.setItem('corrects', corrects);
corrects = sessionStorage.getItem('corrects');
alert("corrects:" + corrects);
</script>
```